# How to bypass HttpRequestValidationException for just one request value without encoding the value?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Stipulation: Cannot use base64 encoding. I've been told to not increase the payload any more than necessary, which base64 will do.

Preferred: Setting `requestValidationMode` for single page to 2.0, but [I don't think this is possible](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Aug/19/RequestValidation-Changes-in-ASPNET-40).

Scenario: User browses and selects image. Front-end will grab the image using, [`FileReader.readAsDataUrl(f)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29), then base64 decode it (leaving me with the equivalent of [`FileReader.readAsBinaryString(f)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/FileReader#readAsBinaryString%28%29), but isn't IE10 compatible), and send it to my IHttpHandler via AJAX.

Currently, this will throw an `HttpRequestValidationException`, because the binary data includes characters that are potentially harmful. This is not a concern, because our back-end will verify the data. How do I fix/bypass this expection on just this data alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a little digging, but here is the answer:

In web.config, add:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" />
```

You can then use the HttpRequest.Unvalidated property to read the unvalidated form value:

```
var s = context.Request.Unvalidated.Form["forum_post"];
```

This is new in ASP.NET 4.5 and called [Deferred ("lazy") request validation](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/whats-new#_Toc318097381).

> Developers have frequently asked for the ability to selectively turn
>   off request validation for their applications. For example, if your
>   application is forum software, you might want to allow users to submit
>   HTML-formatted forum posts and comments, but still make sure that
>   request validation is checking everything else.
>
> ASP.NET 4.5 introduces two features that make it easy for you to
>   selectively work with unvalidated input: deferred ("lazy") request
>   validation and access to unvalidated request data.

For some, you may run into issues, that I cannot say I understand the reason, except that by changing the `requestValidationMode` to `4.5`, it will throw a `System.StackOverflowException`. To solve this in my situation, I only set the request validation mode on my handler, like so in the web.config:

```
<location path="~/Handlers/MyHandler.ashx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```