# Correct way to validate dangerous characters MVC model field after allowing broader range of input

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, passwords

**Our initial situation**:

- We have ClientValidationEnabled =true on our website
- We are using MVC 5 and have a model for the username + password
- We need to allow '<' '>' in the password because the data is sent to another existing system which allows a wider range of characters.

When a password (for instance '< special password >') is submitted a HttpRequestValidationException is thrown.

**Problem description:**

We would like to allow for additional characters only in the password property of the model.

**Current found methods:**

- disable validation on a level (overall, page or only the specific method).
  Downside: 
  This applies to all fields in the input (or even more depending on the chosen level).
- Not use a model and use form fields directly and use this method: [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617423/how-to-bypass-httprequestvalidationexception-for-just-one-request-value-without) -> [Deferred ("lazy") request validation](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097381)
- Specify [AllowHtml] as suggested by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3390350/greg)

**Question:**

Both these methods require additional validation of the non validated field. For these validations we could write custom validation, but we'd prefer using a existing well known solution.

Are there any good suggestions to **validate** the field?

Comment: Can't you use [AllowHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute on password field?

Comment: This does allow for annotating the model to allow for broader range of input (without specifying which), but still leaves the question: How should we validate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but the best way of solving this is to properly serialize the data before sending it to the server. Browsers don't do this by default, but here's a (simplified) jquery example:

```
<script>
function submit()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Account/Login',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
    });
}
</script>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="UserName" />
    <input type="text" name="Password" />
    <button type="submit" onclick="submit();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Although this is not a solely server side solution it does allow for sending the content differently allowing and would allow for additional characters! Tnx

Answer (score 7):

I have an **MVC 5** application, and your question interested me in doing some testing.  As it turns, out, many values using "<" and ">" symbols work fine.

- password> , password<> , password/> for example **are all ignored**
- while <password , and <password> **cause issues**

So, really it is only a subset of passwords with these characters that will cause you grief.

You already mentioned the quick and dirty solution, of just turning this feature off at the **controller** action level:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
    // ...
}
```

But what I think you really want to do is disable this feature for a single field.  Which can be done by using the **[AllowHtml]** tag on the given property in your **model**.

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Password{ get; set; }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Say you have your own login table, and are using an entity framework generated class for your model, then this can be applied as the meta data to another partial class within the same namespace.

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
    public partial class User
    {
    }

    public class UserMetaData
    {
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Lastly, once you get this all working, there is a peculiar behavior I noticed.  If I allow these special characters in a password, and a login with such fails and goes back to the login page it was returning a blank page...  As if there are additional safety features I was hitting.  Yet, I could still login with such a login containing the special characters without issue...

So I ended up having to have my login action always redirect to another action (even on these failures) to prevent the odd ball special character containing password on failed login attempt from causing a blank page.